# How to retrieve an image from the storage folder using image intervention in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: image, laravel, file-upload, upload, laravel-5

This solution works in the Public Folder most when switching to Storage folder I can not get the image and display in the view can anyone help me?

**Controller**

```
 public function profile(){
    return view('profile', array('user' => Auth::user()) );
}

public function update_avatar(Request $request){

    // Handle the user upload of avatar
    if($request->hasFile('avatar')){
        $avatar = $request->file('avatar');
        $filename = time() . '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();
        Image::make($avatar)->resize(300, 300)->save( storage_path('/uploads/avatars/' . $filename ) );

        $user = Auth::user();
        $user->avatar = $filename;
        $user->save();
    }

    return view('profile', array('user' => Auth::user()) );

}
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('profile',
'UserController@profile');

Route::post('profile',
'UserController@update_avatar');
```

**View**
This was the call I made to return the image when it was in the public folder now that this in the Storage folder does not work, does anyone know how I can get the image from the storage folder and display it in the view?

```
<img src="/uploads/avatars/{{ Auth::user()->avatar }}">
```

**Repository GitLab**
https://gitlab.com/ronnyere/Laravel.git

Comment: try this Image::make($avatar)->resize(300, 300)->save( storage_path('uploads/avatars/' . $filename ) );

Answer (score 0):

Use Laravel filesystem to retrieve image from storage
https://laravel.com/docs/master/filesystem#retrieving-files